# Can you Pass A Mock `Document` Into A Jest Wrapper?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jestjs, enzyme

I currently have a component where upon clicking a button, the component's ID is being updated using document.getElementByID.setAttribute. I am writing my unit test, and I need to mock document.getelementId. The problem is I don't know how to pass this mock within a wrapper so it can be used within the test.

My Component That I Am Trying To Test:

```
const Component = (props) => {
   const {data} = props;
   const {
     url,
     title
   } = data;

   const handleClick = () => {
    document.getElementById('NotDismissed').setAttribute('id', 'Dismissed');
  };

  return (
     <div id='NotDismissed'>
       <a href={url}>{title}</a>
       <button
         onClick={() => handleClick()}
         className='closeButton'
       />
     </div>
  );

};

Component.propTypes= {
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired;
}

export default Component;
```

My current test:

```
    const spyFunc = jest.fn();
    const mockDoc = Object.defineProperty(document, 'getElementById', { value: spyFunc });

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Component
          data={mockValidData}
          document={mockDoc}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(spyFunc).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    wrapper.find('button.closeButton').simulate('click');
    expect(spyFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This is the error I keep receiving:

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined]
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to pass mockDoc within the component so it can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document` is a global in Jest. You can access overwrite or mock its properties like so:

```js
global.document.getElementById = spyFunc;
```

or

```js
const spyFunc = jest.spyOn(global.document, 'getElementById');
```

If you're receiving an error about `setAttribute`, it may be caused by your mock not having that attribute. You can mock the functionality in a similar manner:

```js
const fakeSetAttribute = jest.fn();
const fakeGetElementById = jest.fn().mockImplementation((id)=> {
  return {
    setAttribute: fakeSetAttribute
  }
});

global.document.getElementById = fakeGetElementById;
```

Comment: Hm, I see what you mean, but the problem is I still don't know how to pass either the spyFunc or the global.document.getElementById into the wrapper itself?  In the original post, I thought using the attribute document and setting spyFunc will help but I am still receiving the same error as before @James

Comment: @C.Lewis Can you post the code you're trying to test? It may be a matter of `document` not being defined as a global

Comment: I updated my question with the main parts of the component that I am trying to test @James

Comment: @C.Lewis I added an example for mocking out setAttribute

Comment: Yeah this worked!!! Thank you so much! I truly appreciate it!! @James